# Buying World of Warcraft

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm planning to buy World of Warcraft but i just wanted to be clear regarding the entire process.

I've made a BattleNet account and it shows the current offer for all the expansions upto MoP for $59.99.

- Does this include in game time ?
- After i purchase the expansions, how do i get the actual game ? Do i have to download the entire game ? If yes, then how big is the download ?

Are there any ways i can get the **game and the subscription** without having to download the entire game (since my bandwidth is quite limited) i.e **Discs**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I need to buy all the released updates to begin playing WoW?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14348/do-i-need-to-buy-all-the-released-updates-to-begin-playing-wow)

Comment: Please see [This Question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/31689/336) in regards to discs.

Comment: @Jasarien This seems to be a different, similar set of questions.

Comment: Aren't shopping recommendations offtopic?

Comment: @leetfan: This isn't a recommendation though...

Comment: @leetfan More specifically, it's about the differences between digital or retail copies of a specific game, not about looking for opinions on which game to buy.

Comment: Every new account upgraded to a retail account includes 30 days of GameTime.  A new retail account unless upgraded to MoP does NOT include the Cataclsym and MoP expansions.  You can go to a store and purchase MoP to reduce the amount of data but there are 10+ patches released since then with NO other method except downloading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you purchase the game digitally, then you must download the game. Regardless of which expansions you purchase, the entire game client will be downloaded (your account type will restrict which areas you can visit, what level you can reach etc).

The entire game weighs in at around 25GB (as indicated by a Blizzard Support Forum Agent here: http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/8197179898)

If you don't want to download the entire game, you can buy it physically from retail stores (online or high street), and install from the discs. However, due to the nature of the game, you **will** need to download patches which will still be in excess of a couple of gigabytes of data.

As far as I know, each WoW game comes with free trial periods of game time, but you will need to set up a subscription in order to keep playing.

And finally, not to put too fine a point on it, but if you are aware that a question has already been asked, you shouldn't ask it again. If none of the answers in the existing question are helpful to you, you can comment on them and request more information.

Comment: Since i just made this account i cant comment on anything just yet. But thanks for the answer. One more thing i wanted to ask, Do i have to buy the discs for each expansion individually or do they come in a package set for MoP ?

Comment: Also, Battle chest include Wrath of the Lich king expansion ?

Comment: @Traxex1909 Yes to your second question. Again, it is not possible to install WoW from discs alone. No matter what, you're going to need to download a lot of content through their patching service.

Comment: @RavenDreamer That's fine. Do you recommend buying from Amazon or from the Battlenet shop ? Amazon shows a 3 set package for $52.47 + shipping while battlenet shows $69.97 + 25.97(shipping)

Comment: @Traxex1909 Neither -- I suggest buying the digital version from Battle.net, and waiting the two extra hours (your mileage may vary) for the complete digital version, instead of installing an expansion, waiting for it to update, installing the next expansion, waiting for it to update...

Comment: One last question. Does the free one month gametime come into effect as soon as i buy the game or does it start when i first log into the game ? Cos my bandwidth isnt great and it might take well over 15 days for me to completely download all the expansions :(

Comment: @Traxex1909 The WoW Starter Edition is free to play and requires no activation (though it's capped to level 20, among some other things). If you want to maximize your game time, download *that* first, play to level 20, and only *then* bother to actually buy the game. ;)

Comment: Good advice from Raven Dreamer. Blizzard did recently implement some technology which allows you to play the game once you get past  the "core" files. I've never tried it myself, so I don't know how it looks and what the experience is like, but it is an option. Oh... and what Raven meant to say was "(your mileage may **greatly** vary!)" haha!

Comment: The streaming downloader works pretty well. You can start playing with quite a small amount of data downloaded (I think less than 1GB). The tradeoff is that you will get extra-long loading screens when you change zones, if you haven't already downloaded the zone data for a zone you enter. You'll see two progress bars on the loading screen when this happens.

Comment: It should also be mentioned that you can copy the game files from a friends that has the game. Your launcher will then just check what files need to be updates, if any, and then download the remaining. I did this and it didn't need any additional downloading. You will however still need to buy the game (digital or otherwise) and also have your own account.

Answer (score 4):

Buying the WoW Battlechest (base game plus first two expansions) comes with one month of gametime. Past that initial 30 days, you'll need to purchase game time cards, or set up a subscription.